# Obj-C How to delay a function in appdelegate.m?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In the appdelegate.m file I want to delay or run this function     `[HZInterstitialAd show];` after 10 seconds in this

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}
```

I am using Xcode version 7.3.1 . Can you please tell me what should I do or What kind of code I have to run

My whole code looks like this now

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

       [HZInterstitialAd show];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
       [HZInterstitialAd performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
```

Here is the related documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                //This code will be executed after 10 Sec.
                [HZInterstitialAd show];

            });

        });
```

Comment: Why can't you use a simple timer ?